# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x84' in position 424

Tags: python

У меня скрипт парсера на Pyhton 3, в нем прописываю знаки которое встречаются при обходе на сайте доноре, но последняя ошибка не проходит.
Что можно прописать дополнительно, чтобы скрипт игнорировал знаки?

```
                    for elem_photo in save_photo_:
                    result_photo.append(elem_photo)
                    result_photo.append(elem_photo)
                # print(list(row[5]))
                wr.writerow(
                    [res_category, parent_category, category_,
                     '', '', 'false', 'false',
                     bytes(row[3], 'utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'ignore').replace(u'\u2070', '').replace(u'\ufeff',
                                                                                                     '').replace(
                         u'\xd8', '').replace(u'\u03c6', '').replace(u'\u03a6', '').replace(u'\xd7', '').replace(
                         '\xb3', '').replace(u'\uf0b7', '').replace('\u2060', '').replace('\xf8', '').replace(u'\x84', '').replace('\x84', '').replace(
                         '\u0306', '').replace('\u2103', '').replace('\u2300', '').replace('\xba', '').replace(
                         '\u03b7', '').replace('\u2248', '').replace('\u200c', '').replace('\u200b', '').replace(
                         '\xb2', '').replace('\u0450', '').replace('\u25ba', '').replace('\u2265', ''),
                     bytes(row[1], 'utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'ignore').replace('&amp', '').replace('quot',
                                                                                                  '').replace(
                         ';', '').replace('rdquo', '').replace('Prime', '').replace('Oslash', '').replace(u'\u2070',
                                                                                                          '').replace(
                         u'\ufeff', '').replace(u'\xd8', '').replace(u'\u03c6', '').replace(u'\u03a6', '').replace(
                         u'\xd7', '').replace('\xb3', '').replace(u'\uf0b7', '').replace('\u2060', '').replace(
                         '\xf8', '').replace('\u0306', '').replace('\u2103', '').replace('\u2300', '').replace(
                         '\xba', '').replace('\u03b7', '').replace('\u2248', '').replace('\u200c', '').replace(
                         '\u200b', '').replace('\xb2', '').replace('\u0450', '').replace('\u25ba', '').replace(
                         '\u2265', ''),
                     bytes(row[4], 'utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'ignore').replace('&amp', '').replace('quot',
                                                                                                  '').replace(
                         ';', '').replace('rdquo', '').replace('Prime', '').replace('Oslash', '').replace(u'\u2070',
                                                                                                          '').replace(
                         u'\ufeff', '').replace(u'\xd8', '').replace(u'\u03c6', '').replace(u'\u03a6', '').replace(
                         u'\xd7', '').replace('\xb3', '').replace(u'\uf0b7', '').replace('\u2060', '').replace(
                         '\xf8', '').replace('\u0306', '').replace('\u2103', '').replace('\u2300', '').replace(
                         '\xba', '').replace('\u03b7', '').replace('\u2248', '').replace('\u200c', '').replace(
                         '\u200b', '').replace('\xb2', '').replace('\u0450', '').replace('\u25ba', '').replace(
                         '\u2265', ''),
                     bytes(row[5], 'utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'ignore').replace('&amp', '').replace('quot',
                                                                                                  '').replace(
                         ';', '').replace('rdquo', '').replace('Prime', '').replace('Oslash', '').replace(u'\u2070',
                                                                                                          '').replace(
                         u'\ufeff', '').replace(u'\xd8', '').replace(u'\u03c6', '').replace(u'\u03a6', '').replace(
                         u'\xd7', '').replace('\xb3', '').replace(u'\uf0b7', '').replace('\u2060', '').replace(
                         '\xf8', '').replace('\u0306', '').replace('\u2103', '').replace('\u2300', '').replace(
                         '\xba', '').replace('\u03b7', '').replace('\u2248', '').replace('\u200c', '').replace(
                         '\u200b', '').replace('\xb2', '').replace('\u0450', '').replace('\u25ba', '').replace(
                         '\u2265', ''),
                     row[-2], row[3].replace(u'\u03c6', ''), row[2],
```

Comment: А что за сайт и как вы его парсите? Мне кажется, вы какую-то не ту задачу решаете, не должно быть такого "ручного" подхода к кодировкам и заменам, это всё проще гораздо должно делаться стандартными средствами.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Раздел с сайта https://u.to/ofd6Gw сейчас установлена версия Phyton3 на VPS. Сейчас по сути парсер заработал, но пришлось дублировать код символа в 4-х местах. Это явно, не есть хорошо, но пока не знаю как упростить, чтобы парсер не обращал внимания на эти символы. Как вариант попробую обновить версию Python.